# Auto fit Image in html div control

Tags: html, css

I am working ASP.net with C#,

I have a html div which is width 1000px then also i have some image which are different width.

My requirement when i put on the image to div it will show image automatically fill in the that div there is not seems blank space for the that html div.

Note: we have different image which is different width.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `background-image` on that `div` via CSS.

Read about [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), and [**here**](http://whereswalden.com/files/mozilla/background-size/more-examples.html) you can see a demo of the different options.

Comment: i don't need to set background image my question i have different image which all binding to the that div

Comment: you have to explain yourself better next time. Its very hard to understand that from the question.